# JRocket JVM jrcmd shows huge "Other" memory size

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

My application eats big chunk of memory, jrocket jrcmd shows me it has a huge "Other" memory part. Can anyone give me some idea about what it is?

From the link below https://community.oracle.com/thread/3514021, It seems related with JVM itself. Can I tune some JVM option to reduce this value down?

```
/usr/java/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_45-R28.2.7-4.1.0/bin>./jrcmd 27074      print_memusage displaymap 
27074:
Total mapped                  8701648KB           (reserved=1563316KB)
-              Java heap      1048576KB           (reserved=0KB)
-              GC tables        35084KB
-          Thread stacks       521140KB           (#threads=226)
-          Compiled code      1048576KB           (used=6802KB)
-               Internal         1672KB
-                     OS       745728KB
-                  Other      5236872KB
-            Classblocks         3840KB           (malloced=0KB #0)
-        Java class data        59136KB           (malloced=0KB #0 in 11063 classes)
- Native memory tracking         1024KB           (malloced=512KB #8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at

```
less /proc/27074/maps
```

to get a break down of every memory mapping.  From this you may be able to work out where this extra memory is going.  It is far more likely to be a native library you are using if the JVM doesn't know what it is.

Also I would consider upgrading your version of Java to version 8 update 60.  If this is a JVM bug, you might be able to see if this is something which has been fixed (you might not be able to upgrade production but this might tell you something about where the memory is being used)